# how many types we can change args in java in coding

Tags: java

```
class a {
    public static void main (String [] args)
```

Can I use something else instead of using `args`? This is my actual question instead of using `args` can I use `array`, `ara`, `ara34`, or something else? Is `args` a predefined keyword or not? Because without typing `args` why I am still getting the output?

Comment: `args` is just the name of the variable. You can call it anything, as long as you are consistent. (Don't declare `public static void main(String[] foo)` and then try to use `args`.) I have no idea what you are asking in the last question. Still getting what output? (Also, speaking of being consistent, you called it "args", "argus", "age" and "ages" in the same post... this makes it hard to understand what you are asking.)

Comment: Are you asking if the variable name can be changed?

Comment: the name of the parameter does not matter, java looks for the static void method `main` with one argument which can be `String[]` or `String ....`. In fact up until Java 8 compiled java classes do not even know how the arguments are named.

Comment: thnaks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args` is just an arbitrary name for the variable, which you can indeed change to `ara` or whatever you want (so long as it is valid and not a Java keyword). 
Most likely you can change the variable name to whatever you want and still produce output because *you aren't using the variable in your* `main` *anyways*. Unless you are actually using this variable and have the variable name not match where you are using it, it makes no difference to your program.

Answer (score 1):

You can name your variable (and `args` is name of variable) as you want, as long name is [valid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming) and is not one of [Java keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).